# What is a Polar airplane?

Tags: plane-spotting

I stumbled on a new chinese one [here](http://www.china.org.cn/photos/2015-12/08/content_37261878_8.htm): The "**Snow Eagle 601**".

[image]

Can someone expand a little?

At first sight, I can't make any relevant difference from a regular one (It just looks like a stock DC3 fitted with new turboprop engines + snow skis for the purpose).

Anything to do with the plane's performance required by the toughness of elements in the poles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The aircraft is a [Basler BT-67](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basler_BT-67), which is a retractable wheeled ski equipped undercarriage STOL aircraft. It is a remanufactured DC-3 with Pratt & Whitney Canada PT6A-67R turboprop engine. The [modifications include](http://www.baslerturbo.com/power-and-performance.html) lengthened fuselage, increased MTOW, new avionics, redesigned wingtips etc. The skis are added in Canada.

Reports indicate that the [aircraft includes](http://www.china.org.cn/photos/2015-12/08/content_37261878_3.htm) an ice radar system, airborne gravimeter, airborne magnetometer and onboard laser radar system.

It is called a 'polar' airplane because it is owned by the [Chinese Arctic and Antarctic_Administration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Arctic_and_Antarctic_Administration). The aircraft is used by quite a few other missions in Antarctica, like [Australia](http://www.antarctica.gov.au/living-and-working/travel-and-logistics/aviation/intracontinental-operations/basler-bt-67-aircraft) and the [US](https://www.nsf.gov/geo/plr/support/twinottr.jsp), all operated by the Kenn Borek Air.